# ffmpeg overlay with scale in filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg

im trying to get the scale in video input 0 to scale down but get error

exec_static /usr/bin/ffmpeg -threads 1 -i "rtmp://url" -stream_loop -1 -i /slider.m
p4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920:1080[1:v] overlay=20:main_h-overlay_h-80" -c:v h264 -c:a aac -b:v 1980k -b:a 64k -an -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/std 2>>/var/log/nginx/ffmpeg-std.lo
g;

[AVFilterGraph @ 0x556874510700] Unable to parse graph description substring: "overlay=20:main_h-overlay_h-80"
Error initializing complex filters.

i was trying to scale down the video input

Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://url':
Metadata:
displayWidth    : 2304
displayHeight   : 1296
Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 53669.778000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Data: none
Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 2304x1296, 12 fps, 12 tbr, 1k tbn
Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp

Comment: The problem comes from the syntax of your filter. It should be

`"[0:v]scale=1920:1080[v0];[v0][1:v]overlay=20:main_h-overlay_h-80"`

Comment: okie i tested "[0:v]scale=1920:1080[v0];[1:v]overlay=20:main_h-overlay_h-80"
but get issues with video 1 then
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_overlay_1


added "[0:v]scale=1920:1080[v0];[1:v]overlay=20:main_h-overlay_h-80[v1]"

but same error on matching stream and unlabeled

Comment: aha i missed [v0];[v0]
now it works thanks